# Disable delegate of curtain QTableView cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

How can I disable all delegates of a curtain cell. Current edit (when double clicked) is good for me but I need it only on 3rd cell of each row, and for 1st and 2nd, I need to disable any action(delegate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AStandardItemPointer->setEditable(false)

did the job